# Enable/disable button based on condition shows alert two times

Tags: jquery

I have two input fields and two buttons in a row. Like that having 3 or more rows in a page. For each row i need to enable the two buttons only when the two input fields have any value. I gave id for two buttons like this.

```
<a href="#" style="margin: auto;" id="first_link"></a>
<a href="#" style="margin: auto;" id="second_link"></a>
```

In jquery i gave as follows:

```
$('#first_link').click(function() {alert("Some info will come soon")});
$('#second_link').click(function() {alert("new info will come soon")});
```

But this alerts coming for all rows (for three rows 3 alerts showing). How can i show alert only one time for entire table in that page.

Comment: What are ids of other 2 rows' <a> tag?

Comment: u can add u r full html code in http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#first_link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // will prevent the link's default behavior
    e.stopPropagation(); // will stop event bubbling
    alert("Some info will come soon");
});

$('#second_link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // will prevent the link's default behavior
    e.stopPropagation(); // will stop event bubbling
    alert("new info will come soon");
});
```

[**A different example.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/DqLwx/2/)

Comment: Thanks, But i cannot give different ids to each row. Because i can add new row dynamically. So now i confused whether to give class or id to links?

Answer (score 0):

try `preventdefault` or `return false`, thats because the event is bubbling:

```
$('#first_link').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("Some info will come soon")
 });
```

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html